# transaction in cakephp 1.3

Tags: transactions, cakephp-1.3

I have in my controller:

```
$dataSource = $this->getDataSource(); // line 141
$dataSource->begin($this);
if(...){
   $dataSource->commit($this);
}else{
   $dataSource->rollback($this);
}
```

but not works, I get the following error:

Fatal error: Call to undefined method AppusuariosController::getDataSource() in C:...\app\controllers\appusuarios_controller.php on line 141

I have to import getDataSource() ?

Comment: You should post that as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution, I hope it helps someone in the future http://www.amitrawat.com/2011/08/30/transaction-cakephp/